# Chart with amount of rows in each month grouped by year

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following snippet of a table:

```
Name | Date of Aquisition

Foo | 02/11/2019
Bar | 02/12/2019
Xyz | 13/11/2020
...
```

I have to create a line chart, with a line for each year that is present of the table, where the X-Axis are the months, and the Y-Axis are the count of rows for the given month/year combination.
What should I do in this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the data, I would go with Text to Columns from the Data ribbon on the Date of Acquisition column with a delimiter of /

- Next label the new columns - Day, Month, Year
- Then I would go to the Insert Ribbon and select **Insert PivotChart**
- This creates the Pivot Chart Fields to add to the report on the left of the spreadsheet.
- Drag the Year to the Axis (categories box)
- Drag the Month to the Values box and from the drop down change the value field setting from **Sum** to **Count**.
- This creates a bar graph, then you can right click on the graph and select change chart type and choose the line graph that you are looking for.